# Не добавляется новый товар в компоненте DJ Catalog 2

Tags: php, joomla

Не добавляется новый товар в компоненте DJ Catalog 2. Выходит ошибка:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JHtml::tooltipText() in ..../administrator/components/com_djcatalog2/models/fields/djitem.php on line 141

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в классе `JHtml` нет метода `tooltipText()`, который вызывается в файле `administrator/components/com_djcatalog2/models/fields/djitem.php` на строке 141. Проверьте данный класс на существование метода и его публичность

Comment: Как проверить данный класс? я не совсем поняла. На другом сайте с таким же компонентом такой ошибки не было. Джумла 3

Comment: @Елена тогда смотрите версию компонента и документацию, компонент мог изменится или наоборот старая версия

Answer (score -1):

ПРОСТО УДАЛИТЬ ссылку что в 141 строке, по ходу она левая, чтоб стало вот так $html[] = '';